# Does gas of different ionisation energies affect the total impulse generated by an ion thruster?

Tags: forces, energy, electricity, kinematics, electric-fields

Required to do a physics practical experiment for a year project and I decided to do something regarding ion thrusters.

My idea was to create a simple DIY ion thruster (can be seen below) and put it under a vacuum as I feed it with different gases. I knew that the general principle of how ion thrusters work is by ionizing a neutral gas by extracting some of its electrons from the atoms, and thus creating a cloud of positive ions and accelerating it later on. Most commonly, I found that NASA uses xenon due to its heavy mass. For the measurements I am using an anemometer that is placed directly in front of the thruster to get the velocity of the gas accelerated.

Though all this is still theoretical, I have already prepared the apparatuses. But, do you think gas of different ionization energy could affect the thrust generated, or does it only decrease the energy needed to ionize the gas, and the thrust will remain the same for all gases? Or is the only reason Xenon is used, is due to its high mass. Any hints regarding this would be a great help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ionization energy might use some the power that would otherwise go into accelerating the ions. First energy is required to ionize the atoms. Then more energy is needed to accelerate them.  The thrust depends on the number of atom per sec., the mass of each, the charge of each, and the accelerating voltage. (Once the atoms are ionized, the energy required to do that is no longer relevant.)

Comment: Can you elaborate? What I'm really asking is does ionisation energy affect the total impulse generated by the thrusters?